# I have 3 buttons inside recyclerview whose click event is to be set on main activity and not in adapter class?

Tags: android

How can I make onclick listener of recyclerview button in main activity and perform click from main activity.

Comment: post what you have done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a interface in your adapter class and implement it in your activity class.

```
    public interface handleClick
{
    public void onFirstButtonClick();
    public void onSecondButtonClick();
    public void onThirdButtonClick();

}
```

and when creating your adapter in your activity class pass a additional parameter `YourAdapter(yourparamters,this)`
 and now in your adapter
when you intialize your values from construcor assign this to your inteface

Adapter Class

```
    Youradapter(yourParamters,handleClick)
    {
this.handleClick=handleClick;
}
```

now in your onBindViewHolder create onClickListener for your buttons and on
onClick call interface methods like this

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        handleClick.onFirstButtonClick();
    } 
});)
```

so the method onFirstButtonClick which you will have to implement in your activity class will be called.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to do following thing**

> Firstly create an interface for listening on click event from adapter to activity.
>   Second implement that interface in your activity.
>   Third create the instance of your interface in your activity and pass it to adapter.
>   Four in adapter call your method of interface using instance received at adapter and do your work in your activity.**If you will upload code then i will correct.**